# FitNesse Test Page Runs Alone But Not in Suite

Tags: unit-testing, testing, fitnesse, fit-framework

I have a FitNesse test report (GroupByTest) that runs fine if you run the test by itself. It has about 500 rows of data in the table.

The test passes when run, however when I run the report in the Suite with other tests, the other tests work fine until it gets to the GroupByTest it just hangs. The test does not show up in the list of Suite tests but the page is still at work trying to run the report, but it never finishes. There are reports after this test that pass if run alone as well.

What I just can't seem to figure out is why it runs on its own but not with the Suite. I checked the box to skip the report in the Suite and it passes that report and runs all of the others as usual without problem, so I know it's just this GroupByTest. I've tried adjusting memory and the report itself with no luck in fixing the issue and the batch file that runs the FitNesse server doesn't show any errors...

Any help would be greatly appreciated as the results of the suite go out to QA and the Product Manager daily.

Thanks!

RE:
Nevermind,

I removed more rows from the test and it now runs with the Suite. I'm guessing a memory issue? Maybe it wasn't releasing memory from a prior report in the Suite in time to run my report with 500 rows.

Anyway, I hope this helps someone else if they run into this issue.

SOLVED.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from question to indicate an answer was found:

"I removed more rows from the test and it now runs with the Suite. I'm guessing a memory issue? Maybe it wasn't releasing memory from a prior report in the Suite in time to run my report with 500 rows."